# VB.NET System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid. when passing a string to a web service

Tags: string, vb.net, web, service, ioexception

Passing a text string to an external web service, I intermittently get a 'handle is invalid' error, roughly once every 30 times or so. Every other time it sends with no issue.

Can't post specific code but the gist is the following:
1) Create and build object to send to service
2) Instantiate proxy object
3) Call the web service proxy, attachMessage method.

Method that returns this error looks roughly like this:

```
Dim msg As String = String.Empty
    Dim header As New ExternalSvc.InputHeader() With {
        .ip_address = GetLocalIpAddress(),
        .language = "english",
        .mac_address = GetLocalMacAddress(),
        .machine_name = My.Computer.Name,
        .user_name = "WEBUSER"}
    Dim headerInfo As String = "IP: " & header.ip_address
    headerInfo += ControlChars.CrLf & "MAC: " & header.mac_address
    headerInfo += ControlChars.CrLf & "Machine: " & header.machine_name
    headerInfo += ControlChars.CrLf & "User: " & header.user_name

    msg = "Header Info: " & headerInfo
    msg += ControlChars.CrLf & "Message includes this information: " & narrative
    Dim proxy As ExternalSvc.attachMessageServicePortTypeClient = Nothing
    Try
        proxy = GetClient()
        result = proxy.attachMessage(header, narrative)
        retval = True
    Catch svcex As ServiceModel.CommunicationException
        My.Application.Log.WriteException(svcex, TraceEventType.Error, "Services SendMessage")
        Throw New VServiceError("Service Communications Failed.", svcex)
    Catch ex As Exception
        My.Application.Log.WriteException(ex, TraceEventType.Error, "Services SendMessage")
        Dim msgex As String = ex.Message
        If msgex.Contains("User not authorized") Then
            msgex = "User '" & "WEBUSER" & "' is not authorized to communicate with the external web service." & ControlChars.CrLf &
                ControlChars.CrLf & "Service message: " & msgex & ControlChars.CrLf & "Notification Info: " & msg
        End If
Finally
        If Not proxy Is Nothing Then
            Try
                proxy.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                My.Application.Log.WriteException(ex, TraceEventType.Error, "Services SendServiceMessage")
                proxy.Abort()
            End Try
        End If
    End Try
```

Stack trace is as follows:

```
Process Exception: System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.WriteCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Write(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Write(String value)
   at System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener.Write(String message)
   at System.Diagnostics.DelimitedListTraceListener.WriteHeader(String source, TraceEventType eventType, Int32 id)
   at System.Diagnostics.DelimitedListTraceListener.TraceEvent(TraceEventCache eventCache, String source, TraceEventType eventType, Int32 id, String message)
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType eventType, Int32 id, String message)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.Log.WriteEntry(String message, TraceEventType severity, Int32 id)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.Log.WriteEntry(String message)
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is the error message from your code or is it returned from the external web service?

Comment: As advice use `Using` statement to wrap around your stream objects to ensure they are disposed. Seems a cross-thread application where context is not the same for the  entire app life process

Comment: Hard to say without the code as this error can pop up from a lot.  Is this a console application??

Comment: Added code to the OP. Sorry for serious lack of info initially. I just added that 2 second pause today as a bit of a dart throw. So, if that was a bad idea, I can say that that code is not what caused the issue originally. @JimmySmith it's not a console application. It's the backend of a UI for completing text-based reviews. Then the backend pushes the reviews to the external service client

Comment: @AndrewMorton hard to tell because the last point in my code in the stack trace is from the method that calls the external service

Comment: In the method which cause System.IO.IOException (or maybe it’s incoming from another method without try-catch block).
This IOException become from a Stream (Reader/Writer maybe from a local file reading/writing). So, this Stream needs to be surrounded by Using statement.
Is possible in your scenario one of those Streams is catched from another thread and/or application context.  
However using Using statement for I/O tasks is always appropriate everywhere in your code.  
Unfortunately without code all theories are attempts but this one maybe is the most possible in my opinion.

Comment: G3nt_M3caj I found a couple MemoryStreams that did not implement `Using` statement and have fixed these. I'm not certain if implementing a `Using` statement on the proxy makes sense or not but have done this. Unfortunately I cannot tell if this bug has been fixed unless it doesn't show up for quite some time. I will reply in due time with the status.